# give a name to a centos server, instead of using IP address?

Tags: centos, ip, server

I'm working with a Centos 6.7 server and it's getting cumbersome to use the IP address for all my web applications and just basic server usage. I know I can replace the IP address with a name, or basically a domain name I assume, and than I can stop dealing with this IP address. How would I go about making this happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Register a domain and make an A record in it pointing to your server's IP address.